# Intent is null after taking picture with camera

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to pass on a file location and an id via the intent of the camera after taking a picture.

That happens in this code:

```
            btaddphoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Integer vraagnr = Integer.parseInt(lblQuestionNr.getText().toString());

                String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "photo_" + vraagnr.toString() + ".png";
                File file = new File(_path);
                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                intent.putExtra("view", newview.Id);

                ((Activity) ctx).startActivityForResult(intent, newview.Id);

            }
        });
```

In this code the intent exists, aka is not null.

In this code data is null:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Why is data null?
Is it not the same Intent as the Intent in the OnClick event?

rg,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, this is not the same `Intent` as you sent in the **onClick** event. This `Intent` is returned as response from camera activity (i.e. *android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE*). Here (in **onActivityResult**) you need to check if the **data** object is `null` then there's no data returned from the camera activity.

Comment: Ok, thought is was a way to pass information on the photo for. PLaced the picture location and View id in global variables. Now its working as I want to.